# Why is my DateFormatter returning January for every month input?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter, date-formatting

The following function takes a `dateString` and returns the `Date` equivalent.

However, every time I run the function with any month, it will always return January.

```
func stringToDate(dateString: String) -> Date {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()

    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "BST")

    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss"
    guard let parsedDate = formatter.date(from: date) else {
        return Date()
    }

    return parsedDate
    
}

stringToDate(date: "2020/11/13 12:42:00")    // <-- Prints Jan 12, 2020 at 6:42 PM
stringToDate(date: "2020/07/29 09:41:00")    // <-- Prints Jan 29, 2007 at 3:41 AM
```

How can we fix this to display the correct month?

Comment: The correct dateFormat is `"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"`. `MM` is for month and `HH` is for 24-hour time. BTW returning now `Date()` instead of nil when parsing a date string is definitely a bad practice. Just return `formatter.date(from: dateString)`

Answer (score 2):

In order to display the correct month, we have to change the `mm` from the `.dateFormat` property to `MM`

```
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss"

// UPDATED FUNCTION
func stringToDate(dateString: String) -> Date {

    let formatter = DateFormatter()

    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "BST")
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss"

    guard let parsedDate = formatter.date(from: date) else {
        return Date()
    }

    return parsedDate
    
}

stringToDate(date: "2020/11/13 12:42:00")    // <-- Prints Nov 12, 2020 at 6:42 PM
stringToDate(date: "2020/07/29 09:41:00")    // <-- Prints Jul 29, 2007 at 4:41 AM
```

Check out https://nsdateformatter.com/ where you can play around the different date formats

Comment: …and if the time format is 24-hour you have to use `HH`

Comment: This is wrong as well hh is for 12-hour. The date format stil using `mm` for month. The correct is "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" and returning now `Date()` instead of `nil` when parsing a date string is definitely a bad practice. You are also trying to parse `date` instead of the string that is being passed to your method `dateString`

Comment: If you are parsing the current time zone you should not set the date formatter timezone unless you are sure the string will always be BST time

Answer (score 1):

According to the chart,

mm   = two digits of minute

MM   = two-digit month

Corrected Code :

```
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss a" //for 12 hour format
```

or

```
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" // for 24 hour format
```

[image]

Comment: this is wrong as well hh is for 12-hour. The correct is "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"

Comment: He never mentioned about having 24 hour or 12 hour format or Am I missing something? I also posted the chart so in which part I am wrong?? @LeoDabus

Comment: Well the day AFAIK has 24 hours